# How can I show that the conditional expectation $E(X\mid X)=X$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I tried to show that $E(X\mid X=x)=x$, which would lead me to get $E(X\mid X)=X$ but I am having trouble doing so. I know that the definition of conditional expectation (continuous case) is: $$E(X\mid Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,dx$$
This led me to write:
$$E(X\mid X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_{X\mid X}(x\mid x)\,dx$$ but I don't know what $f_{X\mid X}(x\mid x)$ is (if that's even a valid notation...)

I do note though that I don't know anything about $\sigma$-fields or Borel sets, as someone had tried to explain me once. Is it possible to prove this in an "elementary" way?

Comment: Why don't you start with the discrete case? By definition $E[X|X=x]=\sum_{x}x P(X=x|X=x)=...$. Does it help a bit?

Comment: You should be careful because the conditional density $f_X(y | X=x)$ is basically the Dirac distribution and not really a function. Also I would integrate over the variable $y$, because you are using $x$ too often

Comment: If I use the discrete case, :
$$E(X|X=x)=\sum_x x\frac{P(X=x \cap X=x}{P(X=x)}$$
$$E(X|X=x)=\sum_x x\frac{P(X=x)}{P(X=x)}$$
$$E(X|X=x)=\sum_x x*1$$ ? 
I don't know if I am on the right track... not sure how this sum would just give "x"
@Cocopuffs I am not sure what you mean that I and using x too often?

Comment: Regarding "sigma-algebras or Borel sets", I mention that the formula you put forward as a definition cannot be used as such unless one knows how to define $f_{X\mid Y}$--and this is a *consequence* of the definition. Thus, I guess there are two take-home messages here: in your desire to avoid the proper definition, you are running in circles; it is a fact of life that any correct definition (in the continuous case) uses what you call "sigma-algebras or Borel sets".

Comment: I think you have a mistake there. The integral is w.r.t. a dummy variable x, which is summed. Whereas when you write the expectation w.r.t  X=x, x is  fixed number. Call in the first equation y=a and leave it fixed as a parameter when you impose X=Y to pass from the first equation to the second. This way you are not tempted to mix different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually easier to define $E(X\mid Y)$ than $E(X\mid Y=y)$ hence let us recall how this is done. By definition, $E(X\mid Y)$ is any random variable $Z$ such that:

$\qquad$ (1.) $Z$ is a measurable function of $Y$.

$\qquad$ (2.) For every bounded random variable $v(Y)$, $E(Zv(Y))=E(Xv(Y))$.

It happens that when $X$ is integrable, such a random variable $Z$ exists and is almost surely unique, in the sense that if $Z$ and $Z'$ both satisfy conditions (1.) and (2.), then $P(Z=Z')=1$.

When $X=Y$, things are quite simple since $Z=X$ obviously satisfies conditions (1.) and (2.), thus, $E(X\mid X)=X$.

Note finally that $Z=X$ always satisfies (2.) but does not satisfy (1.) in general, and, likewise, that $Z=E(X)$ always satisfies (1.) but does not satisfy (2.) in general.

Comment: could you explain (2) a bit more? I'm sorry.I'm kind of new to conditional expectations. Meantime,I wrote this but I think it's stretching it

If I "define" $\color{purple}{Y}=\color{blue}{X}$, then$$E(\color{purple}{Y}|X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\color{purple}{y} f_{\color{purple}Y|X}(\color{purple}y|x)~d\color{purple}{y}$$ $$E(\color{blue}{X}|X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\color{blue}{x} f_{\color{purple}Y|X}(\color{purple}y|x)~d\color{purple}{y}$$ $$=\color{blue}{x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\color{purple}Y|X}(\color{purple}y|x)~d\color{purple}{y}$$ $=\color{blue}{x}(1)=\color{blue}{x}$

Comment: A point of my answer is that sound proofs cannot be based on "computations" involving the conditional densities $f_{Y\mid X}$ unless one knows that these exist and how to compute them. Which is assuming that the question is already solved. With your last comment, you seem to stick to this approach, I can only repeat that it is **doomed**. // About (2.), I am afraid there is nothing to explain here, this is a definition. Note however that (2.) is equivalent to (2'.) $E(Z;Y\in B)=E(X; Y\in B)$ for every Borel set $B$. This might make more apparent why one requires (2.).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an elementary way to illustrate why $\mathbb{E}\left [g(X)\mid X \right ]=g(X),$ for any Borel-measurable function $g(x)$.

We start with a definition.

> **Definition.**
> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables defined on a probability space $(\mathcal{Ω},\mathcal{S},\mathbb{P})$, and let $g$ be a Borel-measurable function. Then the conditional expectation of $g(X)$,given $Y$, written as $\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mid Y]$, is an RV that takes the value $\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mid Y=y]$, defined by
> $$\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mid Y=y]=$$$$
> \begin{cases}
>   \sum_{x}g(x)\mathbb{P}(X=x\mid Y=y)& \text{if} (X,Y)\text{ is of the discrete type and}\mathbb{P}(Y = y) > 0, \\
>   \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}g(x)f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)dx& \text{if} f(X,Y) \text{is of the continuous type and} f_{Y}(y) > 0. 
> \end{cases}$$
> when the RV $Y$ assumes the value $y$.

Whatever the  RV $X$ is discrete type or continuous type,
let  $X=x_{0}$ , then we have $$\mathbb{P}\left [ g(X)=k\mid X=x_{0} \right ]=\begin{cases}
  1,& k=g(x_0) \\
  0,& k\ne g(x_0)
\end{cases}.$$ Note that $k$ is a variable defined on real line and $x_{0}$ is a fixed real constant such that $\left \{\omega\mid X(\omega )=x_0 \right \}\ne \emptyset$ .

The conditional probability mass function of $g(X)$ given $X=x_{0}$ is given by the following table.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  g(X)&  g(X)=g(x_{0})& g(X)\ne g(x_0) \\
     \hline \mathbb{P}[g(X)\mid X=x_{0}] &  1 & 0
\end{array}$$

From above definition of the discrete type,
The conditional expectation of $g(X)$ given $X = x_{0}$ is
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)\mid X=x_{0}]=g(x_0)\cdot\mathbb{P}[g(X)=g(x_0)\mid X=x_{0}]=g(x_0).(\ast)$$

Finally,let's replace the fixed constant $x_{0}$ in $(\ast)$ with a variable $x$ which varies over the range of $X$,then it will get $$\mathbb{E}\left [g(X)\mid X\right ]=g(X).$$

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the accepted answer:

$E(X\mid X)$ is by definition (there are indeed several ways to define it) $E(X\mid\mathcal{H})$ where $\mathcal{H}=\sigma(X)$. Since $X$ is $\mathcal{H}$-measurable, one has $E(X\mid\mathcal{H})=X$.