# Writing the definition of the expectation $E(X+Y \mid Z=z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I want to write out the "definition" of the conditional expectation $E[X+Y \mid Z=z]$, would it be (for the continuous case):
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x+y)\,f_{X,Y\mid Z}(x,y \mid z)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

I'm sorry I haven't done much in conditional expectations involving more than two random variables.

Furthermore, I want to prove
$$E[X+Y \mid Z=z]=E[X \mid Z=z]+E[Y \mid Z=z],$$
so I thought knowing what the above definition would be would help me to do so.

Comment: Did you get something from the answer to this (quite related) [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/431422/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this, simply divide the integral into two:

$$
E(X+Y|Z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty(x+y)f_{X, Y|Z}(x, y|z)dxdy\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X, Y|Z}(x, y|z)dxdy+\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_{X, Y|Z}(x, y|z)dxdy\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X, Y|Z}(x, y|z)dydx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X, Y|Z}(x, y|z)dxdy\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X|Z}(x|z)dx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_{Y|Z}(y|z)dy\\
=E(X|Z)+E(Y|Z)
$$

This is also known as the linearity property of the expectation operation.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for clarifying that. @hejseb