# Conditional expectation (mixed with an iterated expectation) $E[E(X\mid Y)\mid Y]=E(X\mid Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Conditional expectation:
I want to prove $E[E(X\mid Y)|Y]=E(X\mid Y)$

I attempted the following. Is it correct? $$\begin{align*}E[E(X\mid Y)|Y=y]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty E(X\mid Y=y)f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)~dx\\ &=E(X\mid Y=y)\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)~dx \\&=E(X\mid Y=y)\end{align*}$$ $$\text{Hence, } E[E(X\mid Y)|Y]=E(X\mid Y)$$

Comment: Why the first = sign?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. It helped me to formalize why it is always impossible to define $E(E(X\mid Y)\mid Y)$ through conditional densities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined your symbols for much of this; so, I don't want to say that I'm quite comfortable with what you've written there. Plus - assuming that $f_{X\vert Y}$ is a density function - you've made an inherent assumption that your variable is continuously distributed.

However, let me present you with a hint for a much more general proof.  Remember that $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ is itself a random variable - and in particular, is a random variable that is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$.

You can prove that if $Z$ is a random variable that is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, then $\mathbb{E}[Z\mid \mathcal{F}]=Z$.

(To make logical sense of this: remember, we can think of conditional expectation as "If we know only the information encoded in $\mathcal{F}$, what can we say about the value of $Z$?" If $Z$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$, then of course we know exactly the value of $Z$ given that information.)

Comment: Yes $f_{X|Y}$ is a conditional density function. And yes I tried to prove the continuous case only. 

I'm sorry though I haven't done measure theory so I'm not quite sure about those details. @nrpeterson

Comment: They have you doing conditional expectation before measure theory?!  Yikes.

Comment: Yes. I've seen conditional expectation in 2 different courses (although roughly the same formulas), without any mention ever of measure theory (I wasn't even aware of what it was until I googled some stuff on conditional expectation...)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt this conversation but, @user84226, nrpeterson's point was already made to you, [quite recently](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/431449/6179). Since this was apparently lost on you, let me repeat: one cannot define conditional expectations from conditional densities, even in the restricted case when such densities exist, without first defining these densities. How did they define $f_{X\mid Y}$ to you? (Not to mention that quite often $f_{X\mid Y}$ does not exist, see the conundrum this put you in when you tried to compute $E(X|X)$.) (+1 on this answer.)

Comment: (As a heads up, this is what they defined for us regarding conditional densities and conditional expectations in the continuous case, since we were mostly dealing with continuous random variables): 

They defined it as $$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$ where $f(x,y)$ is the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ and $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal density function of $Y$, such that $$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx$$. 

Furthermore, they defined $$E(X|Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)~dx$$

Comment: When we saw double expectations, they proved it in this way:
$$\begin{align*}E[E(X|Y)]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(X|Y=y)f_Y(y)~dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx\right)f_Y(y)~dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)~dx~dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-infty}^{\infty}xf(x,y)~dx~dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\int_{-infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)~dy~dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)~dx\\&=E(X)\end{align*}$$ @Did
I don't know why the LaTeX code wouldn't work properly when I was using "-\infty" all the way through

Comment: Thus you need (the existence of, and) a formula for $f_{Z\mid Y}$ where $Z=E(X\mid Y)$. According to the formula in your comment, this requires (the existence of, and) a formula for $f_{Z,Y}$, an object which does not exist since the distribution of $(Z,Y)$ has no density, **ever**! :-) To ask you to solve this exercise without the definition in @Daniel Kjær's post is absurd.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Thanks for your input and patience. I guess I don't have a very good prof =( I should take a course that talks about measure theory.

Comment: @Did is it possible to explain this without the use of measure theoretic technicalities? I find this highly interesting as a stat grad student, but I have no background in measure theory at all.

Comment: @hejseb One can probably use a toned down version of the definition in Daniel Kjær's post: for every random variables $X$ and $Y$ [such that $X$ is integrable], $E(X\mid Y)$ is any [integrable] random variable $h(Y)$ [with $h$ measurable] such that $E(h(Y);Y\in B)=E(X;Y\in B)$ for every [Borel set] $B$. And if the [...] are too "measure theoretical", skip them...

Comment: @Did Thanks! Seems to be basically what I came up with after you had criticized my initial answer, only stated more sophistically. It's quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to see what's going on if you also expand the conditional expectation and write its integral out.
$$
E(E(X|Y)|Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty E(X|Y=y)f_{X|Y=y}(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X|Y=y}(x)dx\right)f_{X|Y=y}(x)dx\\
=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X|Y=y}(x)dx\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X|Y=y}(x)dx\\
=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X|Y=y}(x)dx\right)\\
=E(X|Y)
$$

Comment: I do not understand the first = sign. A priori, one should see at this place the conditional density of $E(X\mid Y)$ conditional on $Y$.

Comment: Hmm. You're probably right. I revisited my reference (Allan Gut's An Intermediate Course in Probability), and I think this should be correct: Let $h(Y)=E(X|Y)$. Then $E(h(Y)|Y=y)=h(y)=E(X|Y)$. Or am I still getting it wrong?

Comment: Dunno... it all depends on how one defines $E(Z\mid Y=y)$ for any integrable random variable $Z$. The only coherent definition I know is $E(Z\mid Y=y)=h(y)$ where $h$ is any measurable function such that $E(Z\mid Y)=h(Y)$ almost surely. Then the assertion in your comment is a tautology.