# In conditional expectation, why is $E(X \mid X)=X$ instead of $E(X \mid X)=E(X)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

In conditional expectation, why is $E(X \mid X)=X$ instead of $E(X \mid X)=E(X)$? If we know the distribution $X$, wouldn't the expected value of the distribution just be $E(X)$?

Comment: 1. Look up at least once the definition of conditional expectation. 2. Loosely speaking, E(X|Y) is the best prediction one can make about X knowing Y. Now you know X, then the best prediction about X you can make is X itself, right? Hence E(X|X)=X.

Comment: Hmm that seems to make sense, I think what's confusing me is that I am thinking of it in terms of an average. That is, expectation gives an average. But in this case it seems to make more sense to think of expectation as a "best prediction".

Comment: See my point 1.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431422/how-can-i-show-that-the-conditional-expectation-exx-x) helps