# Prove that $E[X|X]=X$

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

In my statistics notes , they used the following result in an exercise
$E[X|X]=X$ , where $X$ is a normal random variable. They simply stated that if I know $X$, the expected value is $X$. How can I prove that more rigorously?

Comment: What definition of conditional expectation are you working with?

Comment: Is this a statistics class assuming you know measure theory, or is it one where they only assume you know calculus or linear algebra?

Comment: @Clarinetist assuming some measure theory and probability based on it, but we haven't go into to much detail on this topic

Comment: You can think about it this way. $E(X|X=x)=E(x)=x$, where the first equality is "plugging in" the x you know, and the second equality is because x is a constant

Comment: @Keen-ameteur The definition of conditional expectation value with respect to a sigma algebra was the original one from Kolmogorov: $X \in L^1(\Omega,F,P)$ , E[X |G] is a random variable that is 1) G-measurable and 2) for each $A$ $ \in G \int_A XdP= \int_A E[X|G] dP$, where $G$ is a sub sigma algebra of $F$

Comment: @Stacker  that would be conditioning with respect to an event. In my case it is conditioning with respect to a sigma-algebra

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431422/321264 and linked threads.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions linked here already use the uniqueness, but another way to show this is to look at the sets

$$ E_n^+:=\Big \{ \omega: X(\omega)-\mathbb{E}[X\vert X] > \frac{1}{n} \Big\}  \quad \text{and} \quad  E_n^-:=\Big \{ \omega: X(\omega)-\mathbb{E}[X\vert X] < \frac{1}{n} \Big\}, $$

which are both measurable w.r.t $\sigma(X)$. Note that $ \{ X\neq \mathbb{E}[X\vert X] \}=E^+\cup E^- $, while

$$ E^+=\cup_{n}E_n^+ \quad \text{and} \quad E^-=\cup_{n}E_n^-. $$

Using condition $(2)$ of your definition, you can show that both $E^+$ and $E^-$ occur with probability $0$.